# Use Puppet to deploy files to all user's home directory

Tags: user-management, puppet, deployment

I want to deploy a simple text file (a git commit message template) to each user's home directory using Puppet.

I came across [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/200101/puppet-how-can-i-copy-a-file-to-several-user-folders) which seems very close, but the part I'm not clear on is how do I generate a list of users for each node?

In the post they hardcode the users like this:

```
 applink::desktoplinks { [ "user1", "user2", "user3" ]: }
```

I can't hard-code the list because these are developer machines and might have a variety of different users that are specific to each node.

Looking at [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/58790/how-can-i-have-puppet-deploy-ssh-keys-for-virtual-users), I think I need to use virtual resources, but being a total newbie, just by reading the docs and the provided samples I can't quite seem to figure it out.

Can somebody point me to a quick sample or recipe somewhere that illustrates how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate a list of users you need to create a new *fact*. Any information that comes *from* the host that will be configured needs to be a fact.

For example, the following fact returns the whole `/etc/passwd`:

```
# etcpasswd.rb

Facter.add("etcpasswd") do
        setcode do
                File.read('/etc/passwd')
        end
end
```

You put this fact on the `lib/facter` subdirectory of a module, or under `plugins/facter` in Puppet's base directory. I think you need `pluginsync = true` in `puppet.conf` too, but that might be only for older Puppet versions.

You can see an example of this at work on my [puppet users module](https://github.com/dcsobral/puppet-users).

Answer (score 0):

I am realtively new to puppet, so I am not sure if this is possible, but I suspect not.

Have you considered simply transmitting a copying your template, and a script to a single location on each box. Then setup an `exec` resource so that whenever the git template is updated, it will run the script.  The script would loop over `/home` copying the files into the appropriate locations.

Comment: This is definitely the easiest way to go, but I was hoping to keep as much of the process with puppet's declarative style, mainly for consistency.